# ember relationship as promises

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, relationship

I have two related models:

```
//models/school.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { belongsTo } from 'ember-data/relationships';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    zipCode: DS.attr('string'),

    kids: hasMany('kid',{inverse: 'schoolId',async:true}),
    district: belongsTo('district',{inverse:'schools',async:true}),
    grades: hasMany('grade',{inverse: 'schools'}),  
});

//models/district.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default DS.Model.extend({

      name: DS.attr('string'),
      zipCode: DS.attr('string'),
      schools: hasMany('school',{inverse: 'district',async:true}),
});
```

Accordind to the documentation https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/models/relationships/#toc_relationships-as-promises , when I try to get the district by the school, sometimes the district returns null like the school werent related to any district, but all schools are related to the district. I don't understand this.

```
//routes/kid-info.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

setupController(controller,model){ //the model is kid
    this._super(controller,model);
    controller.set('districts',this.store.findAll('district'));
    controller.set('schools',this.store.findAll('school'));
    controller.set('grades',this.store.findAll('grade'));
    var schoolId=model.get('schoolId.id');
    controller.set('selectedSchool',model.get('schoolId'));
    let school=this.store.peekRecord('school',schoolId);
    if(school){
        school.get('district').then((district)=>{
            controller.set('selectedDistrict',district); //the district is sometimes null
        });
      }

},
```

**UPDATE**

Following @Thernys suggestions I have changed the route like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

setupController(controller,model){
    this._super(controller,model);

    controller.set('districts',this.store.peekAll('district'));
    controller.set('schools',this.store.peekAll('school'));
    controller.set('grades',this.store.peekAll('grade'));

    controller.set('selectedSchool',model.get('schoolId'));

    model.get('schoolId.district').then(function(district) {
     controller.set('selectedDistrict',district);
    });

},
```

but I'm still having the same result. It's like the school isn't correctly related to the district. JIC I'm loading the schools and districts before the setup controller call.

Comment: You seem to be going through a lot of trouble to get the `district`, why not just `model.get('schoolId.district').then(function(d) { controller.set(...); });` ? If that is not feasible or not functional for some reason; `peekRecord` is synchronous, so do you actually always get a `school` (are schools populated from server before this `setupController` call) so the `if` block gets reliably run in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

This end up resolving my problem:

```
model.get('schoolId').then(function(school) {
        controller.set('selectedDistrict',that.store.peekRecord('district',school.get('district_id')));
    });
```